# Bootstrap - Alignment issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align around 5 html components in one single line using bootstrap.

But could not and looks ugly like this, breaking to second line instead of being in one line.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <p class="col-md-2 badge col-md-offset-1">Column 1</p>
    <p class="col-md-1 badge">Column 2</p>
    <p class="col-md-1 badge">Column 3</p>
    <p class="col-md-2 badge">Column 4</p>
    <p class="col-md-2 badge">Column 5</p>
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="data in allData">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">{{data.label}}</label>
    <div class="input-group col-md-4">
        <input id="reportTypeId" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="data.reportTypeId" style="display: none">                       
        <datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd"> 
             <input id="startDate" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="data.startDate">
        </datepicker>
        <p class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></p>

        <datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd"> 
            <input id="endDate" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="data.endDate"> 
        </datepicker>
        <p class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></p>

        <select class="form-control" ng-model="data.countryId" required="required">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option ng-repeat="country in countrys" value="{{country.countryId}}">{{country.countryLabel}}</option>
        </select>

        <select class="form-control" ng-model="data.cityCode" required="required">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option ng-repeat="city in cities" value="{{city.code}}">{{city.desc}}</option>
        </select>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Updated:-**

JSFiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/jjayaraman/5dbkf1xw/

Comment: Please create jsfiddle so we can easily understand. www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: @UIXpider thanks added JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for. Took me awhile to figure it out, but I believe it's because you are wanting to hide that first text box, but you were specifying a col-md-1, which made the spacing look out of whack. Remove the col-md-1 and *I think* it's what you're looking for.

I also added some rows, and the container to get some better spacing.

Note: I was toying with the background-color properties to SEE where stuff was on the page.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2 badge col-md-offset-1">Column 1</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 badge">Column 2</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 badge">Column 3</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 badge">Column 4</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 badge">Column 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: yellow;">
            <input id="reportTypeId" type="text" class="form-control" style="display: none">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: red;">
            <label class="control-label">Label</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 input-group" style="background-color: green; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; float: left;">
            <input id="startDate" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="data.startDate">
            <p class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 input-group" style="background-color: blue; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; float: left;">
            <input id="endDate" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="data.endDate">
            <p class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="data.countryId" required="required">
                <option value="">Please select</option>
                <option ng-repeat="country in countrys" value="{{country.countryId}}">{{country.countryLabel}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="data.cityCode" required="required">
                <option value="">Please select</option>
                <option ng-repeat="city in cities" value="{{city.code}}">{{city.desc}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0yd6c7yt/

Comment: Very useful, I would check this... mostly I want this... and  glyphicon-calendar to be grouped and aligned along with text field... I would investigate... Thanks again..

Comment: Ok, so I got it working once the input-group class was added back, but I had to manually set float: left for the two columns that have the input-groups on the encompassing div. Someone with more css knowledge will know why...

Comment: Many many thanks the main part works that s fine for me. I would manage the icon grouping later.